# Can a compromized browser know your ISP's IP even if using a VPN?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, vpn

Let's say you use a reliable VPN like ProtonVPN to browse the Internet. In theory, can a compromized browser betray you? Does it has access to your ISP's IP?

As a bigger picture, if you want to upload some sentive material, can a compromized browser track your activity and report to "someone", maybe with your real IP along?

I'm not referring to Chrome of course, but I consider any browser untrusted by default.

Comment: Define "betray"? Do you simply mean "determine your ISP-given IP?" It's useful if you use technical and definitve terms.

Comment: @schroeder by betray, I mean several ways: tracking your browsing activity and sending your "identity" (ISP ip or some other identity, like a Google account logged in etc) to someone

Comment: So, "can a compromized browser" track your browsing activity? Uh, yes. But that seems outside the scope of the rest of your question. "can a compromized browser" know what Google account you've logged into? Yes. Can it "send" this data somewhere? Yes.  Anything the browser can do normally can be done when compromised.

Answer (score 2):

A VPN only protects the connection to the VPN exit, nothing more. **It does not restrict what can be connected to and what information can be exchanged**. A compromised browser could simply phone home through the VPN and submit all relevant information about what you are doing. A VPN will not prevent such phoning home but instead protects it like all the other traffic. Such a compromise could be as simple as using a malicious browser extension, which includes [previously innocent extension which gone rogue](https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/when-browser-extensions-go-rogue).

Comment: Thank you Steffen. For taking no risk regarding add-ons, I deny  them access to private browsing mode and use that mode for sensitive actions, for  the browser part.

Comment: You can easily configure a computer so the route only goes through the VPN's virtual network device. That won't stop all possible ways to get the public IP, of course.

Answer (score 1):

A compromised browser can do **anything** a browser could:

- submit something *else*, unbeknownst to you
- allowing others to snoop on your navigation
- show you something different from a web site's real content (this is no different than what an ad blocker does - the site has ads, and you don't see them. What is an "ad"? That is for the ad blocker's writer to decide...).
- "enrich" your digital fingerprint so websites recognize you, or think so, and know what to feed you. For example it could log you in to Google Services using a specific profile, so that you enter the "search bubble" of someone else, possibly a synthetic profile designed to generate a very specific search bubble. This way, even Google is co-opted into influencing you.

A VPN is exactly that: a virtual (P)rivate (N)etwork. If the VPN allows exiting to the Internet, anything that is transmitted is still (P)rivate, but it can still *reach an external party of which you known nothing*.

Answer (score 0):

The rant at Google's Chrome is uncalled for and quite irrelevant here.

You cannot rely on systems that are compromised. There are many questions on this site that ask whether the use of a compromised OS or browser can be turned into something trustworthy. The answer is invariably "no".

So, can a compromised browser track you and report that to a miscreant? That depends on whether it can reach the miscreant's computer. That does not need to be real-time: the malware can buffer in hidden files and wait until the VPN is taken down. Or it could initiate split-tunneling. Basically, the malware would run under the ID that the browser runs, and has therefore access to everything the browser has access to, including the output of `ifconfig` (or `ipconfig` on Windows). So yes, including all IP adresses.

Comment: I don't believe you can "sanitize" a compromized browser. But I don't have the time to write my own browser, so I have to rely on a browser or another. Then I try to imagine how much can I be exposed.
For the ```ipconfig``` part, I'm not sure the fake process can access my ISP IP. ```ipconfig ``` lists my local address and my IP inside the VPN network, which cannot identify me, to my knowledge